# Navigation drawer on ImageView click fails with a NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-studio

I want my navigation drawer to open on an `ImageView` click, because I disabled the appbar, but it crashes my app when I click on the image. I get a `NullPointerException` error, but I do not know why... :/

**Error**:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(int)' on a null
>   object reference  at
>   lt.test.test.HomeActivity$3.onClick(HomeActivity.java:85)

**Line 85:**

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

HomeActivity.java, is where I want the navigation drawer to open:

```
public class HomeActivity extends NavigationActivity {
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ImageView icnMenu = findViewById(R.id.icon_menu);

        icnMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START); //error,  line 85
            }
        });
    }
}
```

NavigationActivity.java

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_navigation.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `mDrawerLayout` is set to null here:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

This happens as your layout `R.layout.activity_home` doesn't contain it.

Perhaps you can just do the following:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's giving you NPE because you're using different content view

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

and your drawer is in `activity_navigation.xml`

You need to include your variable from parent activity. Don't create new variable. Make variables from parent activity public to access them. And don't initialize `drawer` three times in `NavActivity`

```
public class HomeActivity extends NavigationActivity {

//DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout; don't create this

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    ImageView icnMenu = findViewById(R.id.icon_menu);

    icnMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START); //use drawer from parent activity
        }
    });
}
```